# The solution of x^2-y^2=z is a regular surface

Tags: differential-geometry

Show that the solution of $z=x^2-y^2$ such that $x^2+y^2<4$ is a regular surface.

My idea was to use the Proposition about critical points/values.

Let $F : U \subset \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$F(x,y,z)=x^2-y^2-z$

$dF_p= (2x -2y -1)$ which means that $dF_p$ is surjective for all p.
Especially for the point $(0,0,0)$.
Now $F(0,0,0)=0$, this means 0 is a regular value of $F$ and $F^{-1}(0)$ is a regular surface.

First question: Is my argumentation correct? I am still a little bit confused about critical points/ regular points.

The second part of this exercise asks for a parametrization of this surface.
I am not really sure how to do it.

I would say a parametrization is
$\alpha (x,y)=(x,y,x^2-y^2)^T$

If the parametrization correct/is there a better way to get a parametrization.